# When and why do you use !! in javascript?

Tags: javascript, compare, comparison, comparison-operators

I came across a javascript program which was using `!!` operator for comparision. I know `!` stands for `NOT EQUAL`. So logically `!!` means `NOT OF NOT EQUAL` which is `EQUAL`.

```
if (!!var_1){
   //...
}
```

My question is why do people sometimes use `!!` and not `==` operator ?

I've read similar questions, but couldn't figure out when exactly do we use this.

Comment: `So logically !! means NOT OF NOT EQUAL` ... no, it means NOT NOT ... basically coerces truthy values to `true` and falsey values to `false`

Comment: [Logical Not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!))

Comment: !! converts the value to its Boolean representative

Comment: the first `!` inverts the `var_1` (false to true; vice versa). The second uses `!` inverts `!var_1` (false to true; vice versa). so if `var_1` is `true`, you would get `true`. and if `false`, you get `false`. It's an extra check for data validaty (I use it PHP)

Comment: It does the same as `(var_1 == true)`, only with fewer characters.

Comment: people use !! to convert falsy / truthy values into a boolean value. a = null. !!a == false;

Answer (score 2):

`!!` is not an operator, it's just the `!` operator twice.

```
!oObject  //Inverted boolean
!!oObject //Non inverted boolean so true boolean representation
```

Some output examples:

```
alert(true); // Gives true
alert(!true); // Gives false
alert(!!true); // Gives true
alert(!!!true); // Gives false

alert(false); // Gives false
alert(!false); // Gives true
alert(!!false); // Gives false
alert(!!!false); // Gives true
```

You see, one "!" just changes is from false to true or the other way around. With two or more of the "!", the process is simply repeating and changing its value again.

Comment: I think you can add that many people simply use as shortcut for Boolean(), yet there are some differences in how it behaves with empty arrays